# Why does my stackpanel orientate its controls vertically when it's Orientation is set to horizontal?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have an Observable collection of custom user controls

```
ObservableCollection<TaskButton> TaskBarButtonList = new ObservableCollection<TaskButton>();
```

which I bind to a Stackpanel in xaml:

```
<StackPanel Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Orientation="Horizontal">
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding TaskBarButtonList}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Which works fine however the actual orientation of the 'TaskButtons' in the stack panel seems to be vertical. Can anyone please help my figure out why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

StackPanel *is* horizontal here and you can test it adding another element after or before ItemsControl.

ItemsControl has its own items panel and you need to change it

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding TaskBarButtonList}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Works a treat, cheers. Right so In my example I had a horizontal stack panel with a vertical items control inside it? So my collection was vertical and if I added another framework element to the stack panel it would have been placed next to my collection, right?

Comment: @Timmoth, `Right` indeed :)